# Single notification for multiple photo in album on Facebook

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am building Windows Service which should upload photos from file system to appropriate Facebook album on Facebook Page. I am able to create and upload single photo. But I would like to upload in the same time more then one photo.

I have tried several ways to do it (batch, fbClient.PostTaskAsync, fbClient.Post) but each time there is notification for each photo. Notifications are visible for users who have liked that page and enabled notification.(see attached files).

My client would like to avoid this behavior, because when manual upload is done for 50 image, there is only one notification. Is there way to upload multiple photos in one post so only one notification will be generated? Someone mentioned about Custom Stories, but I didn't find example who to upload photo in certain album.

Can you please help me?

Thanks. https://www.dropbox.com/s/hnn6sqmxvc3gm9q/img2.jpg https://www.dropbox.com/s/1bc76v49u5dum0d/notifications.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Each image uploaded via the API will always be posted separately. However, if you add the parameter `no_story` to your API call and set it to `true`, it will suppress the news store to fans of the page.

You can then update your code to only allow the first uploaded photo to publish a story, and use `no_story` for the rest.

Example:

```
$photo_uploaded = $facebook->api( $page_id . "/photos", "POST", array(
    'source'   => '@' . 'image.png',
    'no_story' => true // suppress automatic image upload story, optional
  ) );
```

Not the best solution, but it's the only way it can be done.

Comment: How to upload to the specific photo album via custom story? it is not problem for me to upload photo, the problem is when I want to upload 50photos. Upload is done but facebook user who have select "get notifications" from page, receive 50 notification.  idea is to create similar behavior as it is directly on the facebook.

Comment: I haven't tested the notification part, but the `no_story` parameter may work for notifications too.